# I am getting prblm in getting output from ResultSet rs.(with any method)

Tags: java, sql, servlets

Source code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String facName[] = null;
    int rows = 0;
    double scr[] = null;

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    try {
        String sql;
        ResultSet rs;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apj", "root", "root");
        Statement s = c1.createStatement();
        sql="select * from teacherreportA";
        rs=s.executeQuery(sql); 

        rs.last();
        int len = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();
        double score[] = new double[len];
        String facItr[] = new String[len];
        int lenCnt = 0;

       //  ****upto here it is working fine but                         
        while(rs.next()) {
            facItr[lenCnt] = rs.getString("tname");
            lenCnt++;
        }

        lenCnt = 0;
        rs.beforeFirst();
        //            rsM.close();

        while(lenCnt<len) {
            //            ResultSet rs ;
            //                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //                c1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apj", "root", "root");
            //   s =c1.createStatement();

            score[lenCnt]=0;
            out.println(lenCnt+" here "+len+"  ");
            int a,b,c,d;

            sql = "select * from teacherreportA where tname = \""+facItr[lenCnt]+"\"";
            out.println("  !!!  "+sql);
            rs=s.executeQuery(sql);

            try {
                // here rs.(any method) is generating error java.sql.SQLException  out.println(rs.findColumn("tname")+"***"+rs.getString("tname"));
            } catch(SQLException exp) { 
                out.println("  $$$ "+exp.toString());
            }

            a=rs.getInt(4);
            b=rs.getInt(5);
            c=rs.getInt(6);
            d=rs.getInt(7);
            score[lenCnt] += (a*100+b*75+c*50+d*25)/(a+b+c+d);
            out.println(lenCnt+"here");
            sql="select * from teacherreportB where tname = '"+facItr[lenCnt]+"'";
```

Comment: What message is in SQL exception?

Comment: It is only giving SQLException nothing else <br> I am getting no. of rows correctly but then I want to use "rs" object for new sql query but it is giving error there.

Comment: may i add screen shots here?if yes then how/

Comment: The exception shall contain message, attach e.getMessage(). I recommend you to use PreparedStatement instead of manual constructing a query. It is more safe (css) and readable.

Comment: Ya I attached e.getMessage() too but it was giving null

Comment: I am not able to recognize the problem but I know there may be any silly mistake in the code by me....but if you see carefully that before II while loop everything is working fine but after that any method call with 'rs' is generating exception.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? You need to close the result set first

Answer (score 0):

The code is very ugly. I do not like moving cursor to the end and back again. You can totally skip this part when you replace array with List, which is auto-resizable.

The loop is really strange, because you loop over same data like in the first query. Nevermind you must close the result set before executing another query on the same statement.

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

Comment: let me implement what you said...and return back

Comment: no its not working...I tried by closing ResultSet object and then all three objects (ResultSet,Statement,Connection) and then create all 3 new objects but the same problem persist.               Did you mean the same....or something else???